# NodeJs doesn't return Persian/Farsi words correctly

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

The issue is once I `console.log()` a Persian/Farsi word. Node.js logs it in left to the right direction and it makes the word unreadable.

```
console.log("کیان");
```

[image: Screenshot of console]

The terminal logs: `ن ای ک` instead of `کیان`

Didn't find any solution in documentaries.

Also, the data which I store in MySQL, saves as a set of question marks.

Guys, I just figured out that the word is okay and in the proper way when it comes to reading it from MySQL and res.send() it to the browser. So my problem is kinda solved but the console.log() bug is still a thing.

Comment: It's probably the terminal's fault. Try writing`echo کیان` and see if the direction is right. My terminal reverts the direction. Most of the terminals don't have support for mixed direction.

Comment: Yep, looks like it's the terminal. Mine doesn't support this characterset at all and I get only a bunch of quotation marks.

Comment: Looks like a problem with VSCode terminal? I checked Windows 11, there are no such problems with cmd, PowerShell (outside VSCode), MinGW, and Ubuntu (WSL), but there is a problem with VSCode terminal

Comment: @qrsngky vscode doesn't have its own terminal as far as I know. It's using one of the installed in the system like git bash

Comment: @Konrad It is PowerShell in my case, but the font used is different from when the PowerShell is run from a separate window. So VSCode affects it somehow.

Comment: VSCode does override the font: whether it's PowerShell, git bash or cmd. In `terminal.integrated.fontFamily` it says that the default value is the value of "Editor: Font Family", in my case it's `Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace`. And I checked PowerShell (separate window), the font is `Cascadia Mono`. But I don't think the problem is there; even if you change the font to that, the terminal in VSCode will "reverse" the order.

Comment: I just experimented by changing Editor font family to "Arial"; it displays fine in the main text editor, but the terminal will display in an odd way (very odd spacing between letters) and gives a warning saying that "the terminal only supports monospace fonts". Apparently, it tries to force Arial to render into evenly divided rectangles, based on the width of the letter "m". Maybe the terminal (from VSCode) calculates the position of each letter separately, and the logic also affects Arabic-based text (may need to check the source code to be sure)

Comment: Checking `https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/terminal.ts` leads to xterm, and it looks like RTL languages are not supported at the moment: https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/701 (open issue). Also referred to in here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28571 –